# Looking for guidance in creating a helper class for Sql Queries and Windows Form

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

i will try to make this as simple as possible.

I have a working GUI with *SELECT, INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE* (**CRUD**) buttons and I am required to use a helper class and NOT just have the code running behind the buttons ect.

But I have NO IDEA what so EVER on how to even start coding this. I don't understand how I can code an action for a button or a label if i'm working in another class.

I have tried doing "ClassNameHere: Form1" but I get an error:

> lblInfo is inacessible due to its protection level 
>   cmbTable is inaccessible due to its protection level

I have googled that and tried changing classes to `public` and not public ect ect to no avail.

So I have to get this code (this is just the `SELECT`query)

```
private void fillcomboBox()
{
    try
    {
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM person", conn);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        cmbTable.Items.Clear();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            cmbTable.Items.Add(myReader["personID"] + " | " + myReader["firstName"] + " | " + myReader["lastName"] + " | " + myReader["address"] + " | " + myReader["phoneNumber"] + " | " + myReader["postCode"] + " | " + myReader["dateOfBirth"]);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception err)
    {//handle the error with a message
        lblInfo.Text = " Error reading the database.";
        lblInfo.Text += err.Message; ;
    }

    finally
    {

    }
}
```

To work in a different class (the helper class) and be linked to the form so that it works but is not behind the buttons...I hope that makes sense.
But like I said, I have no clue on how to even start coding this.

I would love ANY input, anything at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make a method return a List of strings from your database query and put this method in antoher class (e.g. called SQLHelper). You can put all your SQL related methods here. Make the return types independant from SQL specific classes. Like a list of strings, specific person objects, whatsoever. Make this SQL helper class a member of your Form class and call it's methods when you need to. Use it's return values to do the stuff you have to do.

```
public class SQLHelper
{

    public IList<Person> GetPersons()
    {
    try
        {
            var result = new List<Person>();
            conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM person", conn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                result.add(new Person(){ID = myReader["personID"], ...});
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }   

}

public class Person
{
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
    public string PostCode {get;set;}
    public string DateOfBirth {get;set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ID + " | " + FirstName + " | " + "...";
    }
}

private void fillcomboBox()
{
    cmbTable.Items.Clear();
    var sqlHelper = new SQLHelper();
    var persons = sqlHelper.GetPersons();
    if(persons == null)
    {
        lblInfo.Text = " Error reading the database.";
        return;
    }
    foreach(var person in persons)
    {
        cmbTable.Items.Add(person.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me just make sure I understand this correctly. I place the above code in a new class, and call it from the Form1.cs where I need to?

for e.g I would call the above from form1 for the combobox?

or is that wrong?

Comment: Make 2 new files: Person.cs put person class in, SQLHelper.cs put SQLHelper class in. The fillcomboBox method goes in your Form1.cs where it had been before also.

Comment: hmmm, let me give it a try, and Il get back to you

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for, I don't know I'm having such a hard time finding out how too do this.

Answer (score 0):

separate your database access code with UI related code. in your helper method you can write method to retrieve Data what you want to bind the control.

in your UI code behind page, you can call that method in helper class and bind those data to control and if any error, you can show that in label.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't even know what that is, I'm just looking for a way to set up a class that does SELECT, INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE without being behind the buttons. It needs to be in another class and gets called from behind the buttons when needed.